# How to write data in java continuously in a loop

Tags: java

Below code only writes data when loops completed, I want to write the data for every loop execution

```
FileWriter fout = new FileWriter(fileName);

    for(int i=0; i<30; i++) {
        int lag_timing = getCurrentLag(selectedPane);
        long systemtime = getCurrentSystemTime();
        Timestamp currentTime = new Timestamp(systemtime);
        fout.write("Latency at system time :-" +  currentTime  + " is = " + lag_timing  );
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    fout.close();
```

Comment: for ( ) {
  // all your code

}

Comment: fout.flushBuffer();
the method flushBuffer() from the type OutputStreamWriter is not visible

Comment: Eran meant `fout.flush()`.  In the Javadoc for all to see.

Comment: Thanks Eran and Dawood, its working now, but wiil it be good method if I want to write the date for 5 days or more to any file?

Comment: You use a timer and a while loop

Answer (score 0):

It might be ineficient, but try opening the file, writing and closing it all within the loop, so it opens 30 times with your code.